# How would I store an index mapping in an array to use as variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a foreach statement that I'd like to use a variable in place of index for example.

Right now this works fine.

```
ForEach(vm.trainingdata) { index in
Text(index.foo1.data)
}
```

What I would like to do is this, but because `index...` is stored as a string I'm just getting back a string (which is expected I know).

```
ForEach(vm.trainingdata) { index in

fooArray = ["index.foo1.data", "index.foo2.data"]
Text(fooArray[2])
}
```

Comment: I'm confused what the question is here. Can you be a bit more descriptive? Maybe input vs expected output?

Comment: I don’t understand where fooArray comes from in your second code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's from [an article I found](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-enumerate-items-in-an-array):

> There several ways to loop through an array in Swift, but using the enumerated() method is one of my favorites because it iterates over each of the items while also telling you the items's position in the array.

```swift
let array = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Plums"]

for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    print("Found \(item) at position \(index)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
fooArray = ["index.foo1.data", "index.foo2.data"]

ForEach(vm.trainingdata.indices) { index in
    Text(vm.trainingdata[index])
    Text(fooArray[index])
}
```

of course you need to make sure fooArray has the same size as vm.trainingdata